# How to hang the question/exercise header?

Tags: exsheets

I think below pic should be enough to illustrated what I mean:
[image]

The number 1,2,... are hang-ed to left, like a margin, how should I do like that in exsheets packages?

Comment: It would be great if you could  show us what you have tried. Posting a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that indicates what you are trying to do makes it easier for people to understand what you want. It also makes it easier for people to help you, since they have some code to start from, and hence much more likely that some one will try to help you. If you search on TeX.SX for questions about the [enumitem](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) package you'll quickly see what to do.

Comment: Thank you for your help, Andrew. I have known how to do that via \SetupExsheets

Answer (score 2):

I've figured out how to do it. Just use the `margin`/`margin-nr` heading style:

```
\SetupExSheets{headings=margin-nr}
```